# FreeType2 26.6 size convention to pixel convention

Tags: c, freetype2

What's the proper way of converting from the 26.6 convention to pixel size on the FreeType2 library?

```
pixel_conv_value = ft26_conv_value >> 6;
```

or:

```
pixel_conv_value = (ft26_conv_value >> 6) * some_normalization_im_not_aware_of;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way will work to get the integer value. But, of course you see that you're dropping 6 bits of precision. Another way would be to convert to a floating-point format and *then* scale down by 64.0.

```
pixel_conv_value = ((double)ft26_conv_value) / 64.0;
```

This would retain the *subpixel* precision, if you need it.